# Error 401 with Google contacts API on VB Net

Tags: vb.net, google-contacts-api

I made today a vb net application to fetch my contacts and it was working for one hour then when I try to use my app I get this error: [image]

This is the code I´m using:

```
Imports System.Threading
Imports Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2
Imports Google.Apis.Services
Imports Google.Apis.Util.Store
Imports Google.Contacts
Imports Google.GData.Contacts
Imports Google.GData.Client
Imports Google.GData.Extensions
Public Class Form1
Dim initializer = New BaseClientService.Initializer

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim Secrets = New ClientSecrets()
    Secrets.ClientId = "MYCLIENTID"
    Secrets.ClientSecret = "MYCLIENTSECRET"

    Dim scopes As String() = New String() {"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly"}
    Try
        Dim credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(Secrets, scopes, "email@email.com", CancellationToken.None, New FileDataStore("MYAPPNAME")).Result()
        Dim parameters As New OAuth2Parameters()
        parameters.AccessToken = credential.Token.AccessToken
        parameters.RefreshToken = credential.Token.RefreshToken
        Dim settings As New RequestSettings("MYAPPNAME", parameters)
        Dim cr As New ContactsRequest(settings)
        Dim f As Feed(Of Contact) = cr.GetContacts()
        For Each c As Contact In f.Entries
            MsgBox(c.Name.FullName)
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
End Class
```

How can I solve this issue?

Why this is happening after a good performance?

Thanks

Comment: HTTP Error 401 means that you're not authorized to access the content of a server, meaning there's something wrong with your login credentials.

Comment: Thanks but before I go that way can you tell me why the app work for an hour without errors?

Comment: How would I know? There are an infinite amount of situations that could have occured. Maybe you changed something which you should not change? Maybe Google changed something in their API??

Comment: You didn't happen to do anything in that one hour, like send a LOT of requests to the API?  Google uses sliding windows to throttle a lot of their APIs. You may have exceeded some kind of limit.

Comment: According to the picture you posted the error is on line 75. I cannot see from my phone which line that is, can you share it in your question?

Comment: Thanks, in that hour I did 4 request and I have 35 contacts, do you thing that would be the reason Bradley?. The line 75 its pointing to "Next" line of "For Each c As Contact In f.Entries"

Comment: That's hardly any requests at all, it shouldn't have triggered any kind throttling window.  I would double check all your API keys, usernames, passwords, and URIs.  It's possible you inadvertently changed something without realizing it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it changing the form of this line:

```
Dim credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(Secrets, scopes,"email@email.com", CancellationToken.None, New FileDataStore("MYAPPNAME")).Result()
```

by this lines:

```
Dim credential As UserCredential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(New ClientSecrets() With {
            .ClientId = "MYCLIENTID",
            .ClientSecret = "MYCLIENTSECRET"
        }, scopes, "email@gmail.com", CancellationToken.None, New FileDataStore("MYAPPNAME")).Result
```

And taking out the secrets section.

Thank you all for your advices.

Comment: I can´t believe it, again, today is not working and I did not make changes at all, is possible that this problem would be a Google Contacts API service bug?  I´ll do another question with the details